Sparrow to Remote Bitcoin Core 403 issue
Sparrow v1.9.1
Bitcoin Core v27.0
When trying to connect remotely from Sparrow to my remote Bitcoin Core node, I am getting:
Could not connect:
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://x.x.x.x:8332/wallet/cormorant
Any tips on why I might be getting this are greatly appreciated!
My Bitcoin Core config:
datadir=/data/bitcoin  
rpcuser=a  
rpcpassword=b  
  
[main]  
rpcbind=127.0.0.1  
rpcbind=192.168.0.122  
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1  
rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/24


I had a brain fart. The local node was not on 192.168.0.0/24. I resolved the issue by removing rpcallowip=127.0.0.1 rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/24 and replacing with rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0, which is fine because this is behind a firewall and public access is restricted

try:
rpcbind=0.0.0.0:8332
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
whitelist=0.0.0.0/0
